# I see "Uncommitted changes" but the files are identical?

Tags: git, github, commit

I recently bought a new PC and downloaded the GitHub for Windows version: `1.2.6.4 f054d9f`, then:

1. Logged-in
2. cloned my [repo](https://github.com/ajax333221/Isepic-Chess) to Local
3. made sure files were downloaded locally
4. closed GitHub
5. overwrote `1` file locally
6. opened GitHub
7. reviewed the uncommitted changes (weirdly `7` files listed, only `1` changed)
8. synced to my repo
9. close/open GitHub
10. **search for uncommitted changes (should be none, but there is one with `6` files)**
11. out of curiosity I made the commit and Sync
12. the [commit on the website is empty](https://github.com/ajax333221/Isepic-Chess/commit/35651e5fcab7f2898790dd6b926bbcd7f9ff2801) `0 changed files with 0 additions and 0 deletions.`
13. I am always stuck with these uncommitted files

[image]

**Note:** in the first edit (the one of 7 files), [only the actual changed file is shown](https://github.com/ajax333221/Isepic-Chess/commit/2f266999ce4465764d20439ea7ed8bd65987f1bb) in the commit changes.

**Note2:** the old PC is Windows XP and the new one is Windows 7 in case that matters.

I feel like I messed something up and want to fix it, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As @Oxymoron said, it's probably an end-of-line issue.

Check `core.autocrlf` to make sure the values are the same on both machines.

There's a good deal of debate on what the "right value" should be.
The folks on this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016673/definitive-recommendation-for-git-autocrlf-settings) recommend `false` (and so do I, but I rarely write files that are used cross-platform).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this after:

1. stop tracking the repo
2. deleting the dir `C:\Users\myname\Documents\GitHub\Isepic-Chess`
3. cloned the repo again
4. overwritting my own source files with the downloaded local files

**Note:** Not sure if steps 1, 2 and 3 were necessary

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the way you're checking out with line endings. You can check out with linux line endings, or windows line endings. if these change, it shows files as edited, it could also be the char set.